# How are FIDO and NSA (Natural Security Alliance) different in biometric security?

Tags: authentication, biometrics

Fido Alliance and Natural Security Alliance both work on certifications of biometric authentication. How are those different / complementary? What are their targets for making business for themselves? Which one is better choice?

Comment: This is too broad and too opinion-based to answer. You you also do not specify what "better" means. If you can narrow the question, it can be re-opened.